# UIPasteboard limit

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipasteboard

How many custom `UIPasteboard`s can be stored on a single device?I'm curious to know: 1. What the max number of `UIPasteboard` can be created and what will happen when `MAX_NUMBER_OF_PASTEBOARDS` is reached and someone tries to add another `UIPasteboard` to the device.

Answer (score 3):

I conducted a very simple experiment for your question:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while (1) {
    [array addObject: [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName]];
    if (array.count%100000==0) {
        NSLog(@"%d",array.count);
    }
}
```

Long story short, it's bounded by the amount of **available** memory on the device. This means you'll get a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and eventually, the application allocating the memory for the clipboard will crash.